# Cannot connect to testrpc

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc, javascript

I have a testrpc running on a virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04) and it works properly when I interact with it using the truffle console.

My only goal is to call a smart contract that simply sends ether from one account to another. This is the smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Transfer {
    address owner;

    function Transfer () {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function sendEther (address dst) payable {
        if(msg.value<=0) revert();
        dst.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access the function sendEther from a web, using javascript. When I was accessing my testnet locally everything worked fine, but now I can't connect to it.

The script is transformed with browserify and then included in the htm file as a simple script tag.

The script goes like this:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    /* irrelevant code here */
}

try
{
    // I have to define "source" this way because web3.eth.accounts[0] is undefined, most likely because there's no connection :(
    var source = "0x8691202f56859bd5362f1033fa64e71cb4eae579"; 
    var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"}],"name":"sendEther","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}];
    var contract_addr = getParameterByName("contract");
    var amount = getParameterByName("amount");
    var destination = getParameterByName("destination");
    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_addr, {from: source, to: destination, value: parseInt(amount)});
    var hash = contract.methods.sendEther(destinatario);


    document.write("<br/> Source: ");
    document.write(source);
    document.write("<br/> Destination: ");
    document.write(destination);
    document.write("<br/><br/><b>ABI:</b> ");
    document.write(JSON.stringify(abi));
    document.write("<br/><br/><b>Contract:</b> ");
    document.write(JSON.stringify(contract));
    document.write("<br/><br/><b>Contract address:</b> ");
    document.write(contract_addr);
    document.write("<br/><br/><b>Amount (weis):</b> ");
    document.write(amount);
    document.write("<br/><br/><b>Transaction hash:</b> ");
    document.write(JSON.stringify(hash));
    document.write("<br/><br/><b>Transaction details:</b> ");
    document.write(JSON.stringify(web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)));
} catch (e) {
    document.write("<br/></br><b>Error: ");
    document.write(e.message);
    document.write("</b>");
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Source: 0x8691202f56859bd5362f1033fa64e71cb4eae579

Destination: 0x09b74dc58118140deec480d562651e42ae3b21ad

ABI: [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"}],"name":"sendEther","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function","signature":"0x48c981e2"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]

Contract: {"currentProvider":{"host":"http://localhost:8545","timeout":0,"connected":false},"_requestManager":{"provider":{"host":"http://localhost:8545","timeout":0,"connected":false},"providers":{},"subscriptions":{}},"givenProvider":null,"providers":{},"_provider":{"host":"http://localhost:8545","timeout":0,"connected":false},"_ethereumCall":{},"options":{"from":"0x8691202F56859BD5362f1033FA64E71cb4EaE579","to":"0x09b74dc58118140deec480d562651e42ae3b21ad","value":1000000000000,"address":"0x377D5848c8A7B68D20CcE114f23AD959a62CC9f7","jsonInterface":[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"}],"name":"sendEther","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function","signature":"0x48c981e2"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]},"defaultAccount":null,"defaultBlock":"latest","methods":{},"events":{},"_address":"0x377D5848c8A7B68D20CcE114f23AD959a62CC9f7","_jsonInterface":[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"}],"name":"sendEther","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function","signature":"0x48c981e2"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]}

Contract address: 0x377d5848c8a7b68d20cce114f23ad959a62cc9f7

Amount (weis): 1000000000000

Transaction hash: {"arguments":["0x09b74dc58118140deec480d562651e42ae3b21ad"],"_method":{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"}],"name":"sendEther","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function","signature":"0x48c981e2"},"_parent":{"currentProvider":{"host":"http://localhost:8545","timeout":0,"connected":false},"_requestManager":{"provider":{"host":"http://localhost:8545","timeout":0,"connected":false},"providers":{},"subscriptions":{}},"givenProvider":null,"providers":{},"_provider":{"host":"http://localhost:8545","timeout":0,"connected":false},"_ethereumCall":{},"options":{"from":"0x8691202F56859BD5362f1033FA64E71cb4EaE579","to":"0x09b74dc58118140deec480d562651e42ae3b21ad","value":1000000000000,"address":"0x377D5848c8A7B68D20CcE114f23AD959a62CC9f7","jsonInterface":[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"}],"name":"sendEther","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function","signature":"0x48c981e2"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]},"defaultAccount":null,"defaultBlock":"latest","methods":{},"events":{},"_address":"0x377D5848c8A7B68D20CcE114f23AD959a62CC9f7","_jsonInterface":[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"}],"name":"sendEther","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function","signature":"0x48c981e2"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]}}

Transaction details: {"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}
```

And that's the problem... When I interact with the truffle console, everything works fine. When I try to do the same via web, it doesn't connect.

Any ideas on what's happening here?

Thank you so much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. I'll leave it here for whomever may find it useful...

I wasn't aware of `truffle serve`, and when I tried to use it, it raised an error.

That error can be solved by following the instructions indicated here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/448

I finally can see my testrpc from the browser! :)